# prolog : protein to RNA reverse translation

Tags: list, prolog, concatenation, sequence

i want to show all possible probabilities of RNA sequence in a protein sequence
annexin is the name of the protein.
fact:

```
protein(annexin,[phe,leu,gly]).
code('phe') -> codon('UUU','UUC')
code('leu') -> codon('UUA','UUG')
code('gly') -> codon('GGC','GGU')

rules:
rna(X):-
   protein(X,[A,B,C].
   (i dont know how to permute the triplet codon)

query:
rna(annexin)

result:
UUU,UUA,GGC
UUU,UUG,GGC
UUU,UUA,GGU
UUC,UUA,GGC
...
...
```

Comment: What format to you want for the result? Really always triples?

Answer (score 1):

I think the representation of code/codon has to be explicit, then

```
protein(annexin,[phe,leu,gly]).
code(phe, ['UUU','UUC']).
code(leu, ['UUA','UUG']).
code(gly, ['GGC','GGU']).

rna(X, R) :- protein(X, LC), maplist(code_p, LC, R).
code_p(C, R) :- code(C, L), member(R, L).
```

yields

```
?- rna(annexin, C).
C = ['UUU', 'UUA', 'GGC'] ;
C = ['UUU', 'UUA', 'GGU'] ;
C = ['UUU', 'UUG', 'GGC'] ;
C = ['UUU', 'UUG', 'GGU'] ;
C = ['UUC', 'UUA', 'GGC'] ;
C = ['UUC', 'UUA', 'GGU'] ;
C = ['UUC', 'UUG', 'GGC'] ;
C = ['UUC', 'UUG', 'GGU'].
```

Answer (score -1):

1)

```
code('phe') -> codon('UUU','UUC')
```

is not an usual fact, I will supposse you mean something like:

```
code('phe',codon('UUU','UUC')).
```

2)

You do not need evaluate all possible answers, prolog does it by you:

```
rna(X) :-
  protein(X,[CA,CB,CC]),
  ( code(CA,codon(DA,_)); code(CA,codon(_,DA)) ),
  ( code(CB,codon(DB,_)); code(CB,codon(_,DB)) ),
  ( code(CC,codon(DC,_)); code(CC,codon(_,DC)) ),
  format('~w ~w ~w~n', [DA, DB, DC] ),
  fail.
```

(if you need some postprocess of the result, remove the format&fail and use setof/bagof to store all them in a list).

Comment: Probably the downvote is reasonable, but no comment to explain it or to help to improve the answer?